# c struct pointer issues

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I'm trying to cast a struct into another struct but I'm having incompatible pointer issues within the cast and the **malloc** under `some_func` (structs layout are the same)

```
struct stu1 **some_func(struct stu1 *my_struct)
{
   my_struct = (struct stu1 **)malloc(sizeof(struct stu1 *)*total_size);

   for(i=0;i<20;i++){
      my_struct[i] = (struct stu1 *)malloc(sizeof(struct stu1));
      printf("%s",my_struct[i++]->a);
   }
   return my_struct;
}

int main() 
{
   struct stu1 **my_struct;
   struct stu2 **my_struct2;
   struct stu3 **my_struct3;

   my_struct = some_func(my_struct);
   my_struct2 = (struct stu2**)some_func((struct stu1*)my_struct2);
   my_struct3 = (struct stu3**)some_func((struct stu1*)my_struct3);    
}
```

Comment: You are missing the return statement in `some_func`, and you are probably giving the wrong number of * in the parameter and return statements. Care to tell us what the intention of the code is?

Comment: The intention is that different structures (same layout) need to be filled out the same way by some_func()

Comment: There's a real question here, because you're clearly trying to do something complex, like allocating arrays of pointers to structs, or something, but because you've neutered all the variable names and don't say anything about what the code is attempting to accomplish, it's really hard for anyone to help.

Comment: If the different structs all have the same layout, and are all initialised the same way, why not just use the one type of struct? At the very least, have one struct as the only member of the other two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several problems.

Firstly, you have incompatible types all over the place.  In the line

```
my_struct = some_func(my_struct);
```

`my_struct` has type `struct stu1 **`, but the definition of `some_func` expects a parameter of type `struct stu1 *`; the two types are not the same.  A pointer to T is not the same type as a pointer to pointer to T.

Secondly, your casting gymnastics are not going to work as you expect.  Pointer types are not automatically compatible; their base types must be compatible, and different struct types are not compatible, even if their layouts are the same, e.g.:

```
struct {int x, int y} foo;
struct {int x, int y} bar;
struct S {int x, int y} blurga;
struct S bletch;
```

`foo`, `bar`, and `bletch` are of different types and are not compatible, even though their layouts are the same.  `blurga` and `bletch` are of the same type (struct S).  If `struct stu2` or `struct stu3` have different sizes from `struct stu1`, then you won't allocate the right amount of memory for `my_struct2` and `my_struct3`.

For the sake of clarity and your sanity, you should have different allocation functions for each type, rather than trying to force a square peg into a pentagonal hole:

```
struct stu1 **stu1_alloc(size_t count)
{
  struct stu1 **arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * count);
  if (arr)
  {
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
      arr[i] = malloc(sizeof *arr[i]);
      if (arr[i])
      {
        // initialize arr[i] as necessary
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

struct stu2 **stu2_alloc(size_t count)
{
  struct stu2 **arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * count);
  if (arr)
  {
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
      arr[i] = malloc(sizeof *arr[i]);
      if (arr[i])
      {
        // initialize arr[i] as necessary
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

struct stu3 **stu3_alloc(size_t count)
{
  struct stu3 **arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * count);
  if (arr)
  {
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
      arr[i] = malloc(sizeof *arr[i]);
      if (arr[i])
      {
        // initialize arr[i] as necessary
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

int main(void)
{
  struct stu1 **my_struct = stu1_alloc(SIZE);
  struct stu2 **my_struct2 = stu2_alloc(SIZE2);
  struct stu3 **my_struct3 = stu3_alloc(SIZE3);
  ...
}
```

Yes, the only thing different between the three allocation functions is the type.  However, if the different struct types have different sizes or different initialization needs, then this is necessary.

Notice a couple of things.  First of all, I'm not casting the result of `malloc()`.  There are two reasons for this.  One, as of C89 and later, you don't have to: `malloc()` returns a type of `void *`, which is implicitly converted to the target pointer type.  Two, and more importantly, if I forget to include stdlib.h or otherwise don't have a prototype for `malloc()` in scope, leaving the cast off will trigger an "incompatible types" warning (since undeclared functions are assumed to return `int`, and you cannot implicitly convert an int value to a pointer type).  If you cast the return value of `malloc()`, then you supress that warning and risk problems at runtime (since the value returned by `malloc()` will be converted from `void *` to `int`, and then from `int` to the target pointer type, which is not guaranteed to work).

Secondly, I'm using `sizeof` on the object, not the type.  This has two benefits.  One, the code is a little easier to read.  Two, if I change the type of the object, I don't have to go back and change every call to `malloc()`.

If you ***really*** don't want to have three separate allocation functions, you could try some macro magic like this:

```
#define ALLOC_STU(target, size)                \
  do {                                         \
    target = malloc(sizeof *target * size);    \
    if (target)                                \
    {                                          \
      size_t i;                                \
      for (i = 0; i < size; i++)               \
      {                                        \
        target[i] = malloc(sizeof *target[i]); \
      }                                        \
    }                                          \
  } while(0)

int main(void)
{
  struct stu1 **my_struct;
  ...
  ALLOC_STU(my_struct, SIZE);
  ...
}
```

although I think the separate allocation functions are the safer way to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct stu1 **some_func(struct stu1 *my_struct)
{
   my_struct = (struct stu1 **)malloc(sizeof(struct stu1 *)*total_size);
```

`my_struct` is of type `struct stu1 *`, but you are trying to assign a (casted) `struct stu1 **`

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, do you want something like this:

```
struct stu1 **some_func(struct stu1 ***my_struct) 
{ 
   *my_struct = (struct stu1 **)malloc(sizeof(struct stu1 *)*total_size); 

   for(i=0;i<20;i++){ 
      (*my_struct)[i] = (struct stu1 *)malloc(sizeof(struct stu1)); 
      printf("%s",(*my_struct)[i++]->a); 
   } 
   return *my_struct; 
} 

int main()  
{ 
   struct stu1 **my_struct; 
   struct stu2 **my_struct2; 
   struct stu3 **my_struct3; 

   my_struct = some_func(&my_struct); 
}
```

But this doesn't make much sense. The return value would not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Where to begin ...

1. You must match your types.  some_func() expects a single pointer; in one instance you are passing a double pointer (a pointer to a pointer).
2. Inside some_func(), the 1st malloc() has a type-mismatch.  It is attempting to set a double pointer to a single pointer.
3. Inside some_func(), the 2nd malloc() is has another type-mismatch.  It is attempting to set a non-pointer (the structure) to a pointer.

Inside some_func(), it appears as though you may be trying to dynamically a two-dimensional array.  For reference, there are two ways to do this with malloc().

Method #1.  (Without error checking)

```
struct stu1 **some_func(int dim1, int dim2)
{
   struct stu1 **my_struct;
   int  i;

   /* Allocate space for an array of <dim1> pointers */
   my_struct = (struct stu1 **) malloc(sizeof(struct stu1 *) * dim1);

   /* Allocate <dim2> elements for each pointer */
   for (i = 0; i < dim1; i++){
      my_struct[i] = (struct stu1 *) malloc (sizeof (struct stu1) * dim2);
   }
   return (my_struct);
}
```

Method #2.  (Again, without error checking)

```
struct stu1 **some_func(int dim1, int dim2)
{
   struct stu1 **my_struct;
   int  i;
   char *data;

   /* Allocate space for everything. */
   data = (char *) malloc((sizeof (struct stu1 *) * dim1) + (dim1 * dim2 * sizeof (struct stu1)));
   my_struct = (struct stu1 **) data;

   /* Initialize pointers to pointers. */
   data = (char *) &my_struct[dim1];
   for (i = 0; i < dim1; i++) {
      my_struct[i] = (struct stu1 *) data;
      data += sizeof (struct stu1) * dim2;
   }
   return (my_struct);
}
```

Each method has its advantages and disadvantages.  Hope this helps.